# How can I connect to internet with wireless USB adapter in Fedora 20?

Tags: linux, fedora, wireless

I am at the stage of learning Linux. 
I have just installed Fedora20, but I cannot connect to internet with 
my Wireless USB adapter....

Can anyone help me to use internet in Linux fedora 20?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question is probably going to get migrated to somewhere like Super User, but just to give you a starting point, does the Wireless adapter register as an interface? Run `ifconfig -a` on the terminal and look out for a `wlan0`. 
Then run `ifconfig wlan0 up`, and you can then do `iw dev wlan0 scan` to list access points that the card can see. You can then do some Googling about connecting a wireless card using `wpa-supplicant`.

If you can't see a `wlan0` interface in `ifconfig` it could be that you don't have the drivers for your Wifi card. You'll need to Google which drivers are required and you might be able to get a kernel module or driver binary from somewhere on the internet.

Comment: Thanks Kells, I couldn't find wlan0 so I need to find the way to install a driver for the wifi adapter. It is so complicated to learn linux......

Comment: The fedora20 is installed in my flash drive , and I just found out that I connected to wireless internet at school with the fedora. It does not work with the USB adapter. Do you think I should find a particular driver for the adapter?